# Different style to column in table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to give different style to the last column of a table, but I have no idea how I can do this. I added column `<th>Buy</th>` and it's working normal as the other `<th>..</th>` but I would like to give different style to the last column.
Also tried to write something like **`<th th-1>Buy</th th-1>`** but no effect.
Please, if someone has any idea share :)

Here is the code:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th th-1>Buy</th th-1>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th th-1>Buy</th th-1>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>DEF</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
                <td><div class="checkbox pull-right">
                <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> Buy this player
                </label>
                </div></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: `<th th-1>Buy</th th-1>` – that is just nonsense, you can not simply invent your own attributes and then expect anything to happen. You could f.e. use a `class` instead to identify those `th`/`td` elements, or `th:last-child` or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What style do you need?
You can make all you want with css:

```
  .display td:last-child,
  .display th:last-child {
         background-color: green; 
  }
```

With this code, you will see the last column in green background.

Comment: you sure as its not working?

Comment: I would like just to set my own widht to this column

Comment: could you give me the html also?

Comment: @Marcos remove , from second line plz

Comment: I don't remove nothing. This code works. The original HTML is bad. `<th th-1>Buy</th th-1>` that `th-1` it's an invention

Comment: the " , " was the problem, Thanks Alot!

Comment: Oh yeah, it's a keyboard mistake. I promise that I don't write the second comma!! hahahaa sorry for the syntax mistake.

Comment: Marcos. told you that , is creating problem.

Comment: @ИванДимитров if this solves your problem, please, select this answer as correct. Thank you :)

Comment: in 2min :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you have an option to define a custom attribute `th-1` then you can also use `class` in it's place, and it will work.

Same thing is with a css option @Marcos Pérez Gude wrote in his answer, but I'd suggest applying it just to the `th` element, and using `last-of-type`.
https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/

> **:last-child** - Selects the last element within a parent.
>
> **:last-of-type** - Selects the last element of this type within any parent. So if you have two divs, each had within it a paragraph, image, paragraph,
>   image. Then div img:last-of-type would select the last image inside
>   the first div and the last image inside the second div.

```css
.display th:last-of-type {
  background-color: green; 
}
```

```html
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Buy</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Buy</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>DEF</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
                <td><div class="checkbox pull-right">
                <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> Buy this player
                </label>
                </div></td>
            </tr>
       </tbody>
  </table>
```